# Using regex to remove key value in string

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string in the form of `[stringKey1:stringValue1][stringKey2:stringValue2][stringKey3:stringValue3]`.

I'm having trouble using regex to remove the the string between `[]` using a `stringKey`.

What Im trying to do is

```
const string = "[stringKey1:stringValue1][stringKey2:stringValue2][stringKey3:stringValue3]";

const newString = removeStringKey("stringKey2");

newString === "[stringKey1:stringValue1][stringKey3:stringValue3]"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regex replacement:

```js
function removeStringKey(key, input) {
    var re = new RegExp("\\[" + key + ":.*?\\]");
    return input.replace(re, "");
}

const string = "[stringKey1:stringValue1][stringKey2:stringValue2][stringKey3:stringValue3]";
console.log(removeStringKey("stringKey2", string));
```